# Bell Curve Gaussian Algorithm (Python and/or C#)

Tags: c#, python, algorithm

Here's a somewhat simplified example of what I am trying to do. 
Suppose I have a formula that computes credit points, but the formula has no constraints (for example, the score might be 1 to 5000). And a score is assigned to 100 people.

Now, I want to assign a "normalized" score between 200 and 800 to each person, based on a bell curve. So for example, if one guy has 5000 points, he might get an 800 on the new scale.  The people with the middle of my point range will get a score near 500.  In other words, 500 is the median?

A similar example might be the old scenario of "grading on the curve", where a the bulk of the students perhaps get a C or C+.

I'm not asking for the code, either a library, an algorithm book or a website to refer to.... I'll probably be writing this in Python (but C# is of some interest as well). There is NO need to graph the bell curve. My data will probably be in a database and I may have even a million people to which to assign this score, so scalability is an issue.

Thanks.

Comment: "based on a bell curve" - what if your input data is { 50 people with 2000 points, 50 people with 4000 points } ? What should your normalized score look like then? Sure, "it probably won't be like that", but you need to decide what should happen to *all* kinds of input data before you can find an algorithm to perform the transformation. If you want to *assume* normality of the input data, just find its mean and variance and then scale it - but you might not get what you want...

Comment: The points will continue to accumulate over time, even years.  But I want the reported score to be like a credit score that is always 200 to 800. So basically, when one persons score goes up, he can cause other people to move down.

Answer (score 4):

The important property of the bell curve is that it describes normal distribution, which is a simple model for many natural phenomena. I am not sure what kind of "normalization" you intend to do, but it seems to me that current score already complies with normal distribution, you just need to determine its properties (mean and variance) and scale each result accordingly.

Comment: Like the "grading on the curve" scenario, suppose I have 100 students, I only want for example 2 A+, 4 A, 7 A-, 12 B+, 18B, 24 B-, etc... (just estimating the numbers for the sake of this post....)

Comment: Ok, suppose I do mean and variance as per here: http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_to_find_the_variance_of_a_set_of_numbers.  Now, how do I scale that to a scale of 200 to 800?

Answer (score 1):

References:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grading_on_a_curve
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile
(see also: gaussian function)

I think the approach that I would try would be to compute the mean (average) and standard deviation (average distance from the average).  I would then choose parameters to fit to my target range.  Specifically, I would choose that the mean of the input values map to the value 500, and I would choose that 6 standard deviations consume 99.7% of my target range.  Or, a single standard deviation will occupy about 16.6% of my target range.

Since your target range is 600 (from 200 to 800), a single standard deviation would cover 99.7 units.  So a person who obtains an input credit score that is one standard deviation above the input mean would get a normalized credit score of 599.7.

So now:

```
# mean and standard deviation of the input values has been computed.
for score in input_scores:
  distance_from_mean = score - mean
  distance_from_mean_in_standard_deviations = distance_from_mean / stddev
  target = 500 + distance_from_mean_in_standard_deviations * 99.7
  if target < 200:
    target = 200
  if target > 800:
    target = 800
```

This won't necessarily map the median of your input scores to 500.  This approach assumes that your input is more-or-less normally distributed and simply translates the mean and stretches the input bell curve to fit in your range.  For inputs that are significantly not bell curve shaped, this may distort the input curve rather badly.

A second approach is to simply map your input range to our output range:

```
for score in input_scores:
  value = (score - 1.0) / (5000 - 1)
  target = value * (800 - 200) + 200
```

This will preserve the shape of your input, but in your new range.

A third approach is to have your target range represent percentiles instead of trying to represent a normal distribution.  1% of people would score between 200 and 205; 1% would score between 794 and 800.  Here you would rank your input scores and convert the ranks into a value in the range 200..600.  This makes full use of your target range and gives it an easy to understand interpretation.